# Is LayerSwitcher a future feature in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers-3

Is there any plan to include LayerSwitcher control in future releases of OpenLayers 3?

Comment: I cannot answer the question, but maybe you will find this useful: https://github.com/walkermatt/ol3-layerswitcher

Comment: I'm aware of that. But i'm looking for official inclusion of that feature in OpenLayers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no plans to include a layer switcher in OpenLayers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although i can understand why they have stopped supporting Google Maps in version 3, i can't understand why they have remove this useful control.

Comment: You can use the very good layer switcher that was linked in a comment to your question. The reason why OpenLayers 3 does not have much of a UI is because everyone has a different taste, and it is simple to bind HTML elements to OpenLayers objects and collections.

Comment: Thanks  ahocevar. So, maybe it's a good idea to have a kind of plugin beside OpenLayers which simplifies these things (like jQuery has JQuery UI). I'm currently started working on OL 3 and i just understood there is no filter, no layerswtcher, no popup, even defining WFS layer has become more complex. I know all of them can be done via coding, but a plugin may simplify all of them to at least beginner users. thanks again for your help